# Java KeyAdapter

Tags: java, keyevent

I am somewhat unfamiliar with how the Java `KeyAdapter` works, and am getting unexpected results with the following code using `KeyAdapter`. The problem occurs when a key is pressed while another key is already held down, regardless of whether `isKeyPressed()` is called.

Note: I know this is a lot of code, and I apologize. I tried the best I could to isolate it, and I think it resides primarily around the comments in the `keyHandler` method below (how `keyHandler()` puts the keys currently pressed into `keysHeld`). Hopefully the thorough comments are helpful.

keyHandler:

```
ArrayList keysHeld = new ArrayList<KeyEvent>();

private void keyHandler()
{
    KeyAdapter keyListnr = new KeyAdapter()
    {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        { 
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

            int index = 0;
            boolean found = false;
            while(!found && index<keysHeld.size()) //While not already found, and end of ArrayList not reached
            {
                System.out.print("errorCheck: keysHeld: "+keysHeld+", "+(Object)keyCode+" "); //PRINT
                if(keysHeld.get(index) == (Object)keyCode)
                {
                    System.out.println("found"); //PRINT
                    found = true; //This key is already recognized as held
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("not found"); //PRINT
                    //This key is not recognized as held
                }
            }
            if(!found) //If key must be added to keysHeld
            {
                keysHeld.add(keyCode); //Add to list of held keys
            }
        System.out.println(keysHeld.toString()); //PRINT ArrayList of all held keys
    } //end of keyPressed


        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) //similar in concept to keyPressed
        {
         int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

         int index = 0;
         boolean found = false;
         while(!found && index < keysHeld.size())
         {
          if(keysHeld.get(index) == (Object)keyCode)
          {
           keysHeld.remove(index); //remove key from keysHeld
           found = true;
          }
          else
          {
           index++;
          }
         }
         System.out.println(keysHeld.toString()); //PRINT ArrayList of all held keys
        } //end of keyReleased
    };
    addKeyListener( keyListnr );
}
```

isKeyHeld:

```
public boolean isKeyHeld(int e)
{
 int keyCode = e;
 Object key = (Object)keyCode;

 if(!keysHeld.isEmpty())
 {
  int index = 0;
  while(index<keysHeld.size())
  {
   if(keysHeld.get(index) == key)
   {
    return true;
   }
   index++;
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```

Console output: (held leftArrow[37], and then pressed rightArrow[39])

```
[37]
errorCheck: keysHeld: [37], 39 not found
errorCheck: keysHeld: [37], 39 not found
errorCheck: keysHeld: [37], 39 not found
errorCheck: keysHeld: [37], 39 not found
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple points:

- You aren't populating your `keysHeld` array with instances of `KeyEvent`, but with autoBoxed `Integer` objects derived from the `int` keyCodes.
- You need to increment your `index` variable if you want to get out of the `while` loop in `keyPressed`
- You shouldnt use `==` to compare the two `Objects` in your `while` loop

You can test with something like the following:

```
    if(keysHeld.get(index++).equals(new Integer(keyCode))
```

Comment: Yeah, incrementing index did it. Must've missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When handling multiple keys, it's best to use the `keyReleased(KeyEvent)` method: it makes it easier to handle multiple key combinations during a key release.

What I've noticed was that when inside the `keyPressed()`, I would only get to capture one key character.  On a `keyReleased`, I was able to capture multiple characters (such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>).